# Question about Correspondences from Mumford’s Complex Projective Varieties

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, divisors, projective-varieties

I study David Mumford's Algebraic Geometry I - Complex Projective Varieties
and have some problems to understand a step in the proof of **Lemma 6.7 (b)**.
Firstly, the general setting & preparations  around the problem I intend to present below (pages 97/98):

[image]

Some remarks on used notations: For a rational map $Z: X \dashrightarrow \mathbb{P}^m$
Mumford uses the notation "$Z$" ambiguously. On the one hand for rational map itself,
on the other hand he associates to the rational map a closed subvariety
$Z \subset X \times \mathbb{P}^n$ which he calls "correspondence", noted also by $Z$:
(See also Def 2.15 page 29)

[image]

I think that if $Z: X \to \mathbb{P}^m= \operatorname{Proj} \mathbb{C} [Y_0,...,Y_m]$
is moreover a regular map defined by
$x \to [f_0(x):...f_m(x)]$ then $Z \subset X \times \mathbb{P}^m$ coinsides with
vanishing locus $V(..., f_i Y_j - f_j Y_i,... ) \subset X \times \mathbb{P}^m$.
First question is does this closed subvariety $V$ coinside exactly with the closure of graph
$\Gamma_Z$ of $Z$ of we assume that $Z$ is a regular map?

Another probably not well known notation Mumford uses is $Z[S]$ for closed $S \subset X$.
Here the definition (see Cor. 2.26 page 35):

[image]

Having the background now we now come to my actual problem:

[image]

**PROBLEM:** I not understand following argument from proof on 6.7 (b) (p 98):

For $H:=V(l)= V(\sum \alpha_i Y_i)$ and $H_i := V(Y_i)$, we observe that because of

$$((Y_i/l) \circ Z) = Z^*(H_i) -Z^*(H)$$

all $f_i=(Y_i/l) \circ Z$ have over $X \backslash \operatorname{Supp} Z^*(H)$
no poles. (because over this subset the divisor $(f_i)$ is positive)

But why does this observation imply that over $X \backslash \operatorname{Supp} Z^*(H)$
the correspondence $Z$ (considered again as subset of $X \times \mathbb{P}^n$) is contained in
$V(..., f_i Y_j - f_j Y_i,...) \subset X \times \mathbb{P}^m$? That is
in the locus of zeros of $f_i Y_j - f_j Y_i$ for $0 \le i,j \le m$?

In other words why the condition that $f_i$ have **no** poles over
$X \backslash \operatorname{Supp} Z^*(H)$ suffice, to conclude that
$Z \subset V(..., f_i Y_j - f_j Y_i,...)$? Why is this assumption
on the $f_i$ it neccessary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $U$ be the open subset of $X$ where $Z$ defines a regular map. Let's consider the map: $U \cap (X \ \backslash \ \mathrm{Supp} \ Z^*H) \longrightarrow \mathbb{P}^n$ defined by:
$$ x \longrightarrow \left[ \dfrac{Y_0 \circ Z}{l \circ Z}(x), \ldots, \dfrac{Y_m \circ Z}{l \circ Z}(x) \right] $$

Let us denote by $\tilde{Z} \subset (U \cap (X \ \backslash \ \mathrm{Supp} \ Z^*H)) \times \mathbb{P}^m$ the correspondance defining this map. Using the remark you made about the equtions for the graph of a regular map $U \cap (X \ \backslash \ \mathrm{Supp} \ Z^*H) \longrightarrow \mathbb{P}^m$, we find that over $(U \cap X \ \backslash \ \mathrm{Supp} \ Z^*H)$, $\tilde{Z}$ is included in the zero locus of $(f_iY_j-f_jY_i)_{0 \leq i,j \leq m}$ where $f_i = \dfrac{Y_i \circ Z}{l \circ Z}$.

Since $Y_i$ is the projection on the $i$-th coordinate and the denominator $l \circ Z$ does not vanish on $X \ \backslash \ \mathrm{Supp} \ Z^*H$ (by definition of $Z^*H$), the regular map $U \cap (X \ \backslash \ \mathrm{Supp} \ Z^*H) \longrightarrow \mathbb{P}^n$ defined by:
$$ x \longrightarrow \left[ \dfrac{Y_0 \circ Z}{l \circ Z}(x), \ldots, \dfrac{Y_m \circ Z}{l \circ Z}(x) \right] $$
is equal to the regular map $Z : U \cap (X \ \backslash \ \mathrm{Supp} \ Z^*H) \longrightarrow \mathbb{P}^m$. As a consequence, we have :

$$ Z \cap \bigg(U \cap (X \ \backslash \ \mathrm{Supp} \ Z^*H) \times \mathbb{P}^n \bigg) = \tilde{Z}.$$

As $Z$ is assumed to be irreducible, $Z \cap \bigg(X \ \backslash \ \mathrm{Supp} \ Z^*H \times \mathbb{P}^n \bigg)$ is also irreducible and we deduce from the above equality that  $Z$ is also included in the vanishing locus of  $(f_iY_j-f_jY_i)_{0 \leq i,j \leq m}$ over $X \ \backslash \ \mathrm{Supp} \ Z^*H$.

Comment: The first part I not understand. You wrote that since all $\dfrac{Y_i \circ Z}{l \circ Z}$ have no poles on $X \ \backslash \ \mathrm{Supp} \ Z^*H$, the map $X \ \backslash \ \mathrm{Supp} \ Z^*H \longrightarrow \mathbb{P}^{m}, x \mapsto\left[ \dfrac{Y_0 \circ Z}{l \circ Z}(x), \ldots, \dfrac{Y_m \circ Z}{l \circ Z}(x) \right]$ is regular. But what, if there exist a $x \in X \ \backslash \ \mathrm{Supp} \ Z^*H$ with $\dfrac{Y_i \circ Z}{l \circ Z}(x)=0$ for all $i$. then this map to $\mathbb{P}^{m}$ is a priori not well defined.

Comment: What we definitely can deduce from the information that $\dfrac{Y_i \circ Z}{l \circ Z}$ have no poles, that $\dfrac{Y_i \circ Z}{l \circ Z} \in k[X \ \backslash \ \mathrm{Supp} \ Z^*H] = H^0(X \ \backslash \ \mathrm{Supp} \ Z^*H, O_X)$, ie that $\dfrac{Y_i \circ Z}{l \circ Z}$ live in  coordinate ring of $X \ \backslash \ \mathrm{Supp} \ Z^*H$.

Comment: So if we take affine pieces $U \subset X \ \backslash \ \mathrm{Supp} \ Z^*H$ and $V \subset \mathbb{P}^{m}$ with wlog $V \cong \mathbb{A}^{m}$ and that $V$ contains the image of $U$, then the restriction map $U \cap (X \ \backslash \ \mathrm{Supp} \ Z^*H) \to \mathbb{A}^{m}$ given by $x \mapsto \left( \dfrac{Y_0 \circ Z}{l \circ Z}(x), \ldots, \dfrac{Y_m \circ Z}{l \circ Z}(x) \right)$ is well defined. Did you possibly had this in mind?

Comment: I made some further clarifications. Hope I reached the textbook standards...

Comment: Ok I see, choosing open,  small enough $U \subset X$ our restricted map becomes regular and the subsequent arguments I understand.

Comment: One general aspect about correspondences still confuses me: 
Assume we have two arbitrary closed subvarieties $X \subset \mathbb{P}^n$ and 
$Y \subset \mathbb{P}^m$ and a rational map 
$f: X \dashrightarrow Y$. Can the associated correpondence
$Z:= Z_f \subset X \times Y$ be described explicitly? 

What we know is that there exist an open $ U \subset X$ such that
the restriction $f \vert _U: U \to Y$ is a **regular map** given by
$ x \mapsto [f_0(x):...: f_m(x)]$ with $f_i \in k[U]$.

Comment: Then as I remarked above
the corresponence $Z_U$ of the **restriction** $f \vert _U$ is defined as 
closed subvariety $V(..., f_i Y_j - f_j Y_i,... ) \subset U \times Y$. That's what 
we know. 

But what about the correspondence
$Z:=Z_f\subset X \times Y $? Does it have an explicit description?
Clearly $Z_U \subset Z$ and the closure $\overline{Z_U}$ considered as
subset of $X \times Y $ is contaned in $Z$ as well. But is $\overline{Z_U}
\subset Z$ in general a proper inequality? If yes, why?

Comment: One other question,  one other post? I think I properly answered that one.

Comment: Yes sorry, you are right, of course you answer the initial question properly. I will post my concern from last comments as a separate question.